# Is acetic acid aggressive to rubber?

Tags: organic-chemistry

There seems to be an endless debate about using vinegar as rinse aid in dishwashers, which is explicitly allowed in some models (such as [Miele](https://www.miele.com.au/pmedia/ZGA/TX2070/9585880-000-01_9585880-01.pdf), see p. 25) but usually not mentioned in user's manual. The main contra argument is that acetic acid is somehow destroying the rubber seals, leading to malfunction. On the other hand, common commercial rinse aids also contain various acids (e.g. see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=H6CPSH9qaIEC&pg=PA127), 5.7% glycolic acid). Also, I haven't heard about rubber being sensitive to acids, at least to weak ones.

Is there a specific property of acetic acid I'm not aware of that makes it aggressive to rubber?

PS. I have asked a related question [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35374/is-vinegar-dangerous-for-dishwashers).

Comment: I think you thing that's missing in your question is what kind of "rubber?" There are all sorts of rubbery plastics that could be used as O-rings or what not, and these substances don't all behave the same way towards acids...

Comment: @Zhe If you have an example of a polymer which is sensitive to acetic acid while being tolerant to citric or glycolic acid, that would constitute an answer I'd happily upvote.

Comment: No, I don't. I'm not a polymer chemist, but in principle, this is something that could be the case.